# Reverb bus workflow for features (and bouncing DX+M&E)

Tags: reverb, me

I've read in forums that people have reverb busses (around 3-5) to send dx-fx-mx to. Is this per food group (3 for DX, 3 for FX, etc..) or for everything since you want the DX and FX to be in the same room?

I ask this because I've had problems before because I needed to bounce elements of a whole film -- DX, FX, MX. I wanted to be able to bounce them all at once via routing but since my reverbs are shared by DX and FX, my M&E is all messed up. I resorted to bouncing them one by one, (making all other food groups inactive) instead of being able to bounce all elements at the same time. But this took a lot of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will have multiple reverbs with the same setting routed accordingly if I need a room for more than 1 group.  Otherwise it stops you from printing  your mix and all the associated splits and deliverables in one pass.